# Datanucleus ANT enhancement cannot find my classes to enhance

Tags: ant, datanucleus

I'm using this because the enhancer plugin couldn't handle long `CLASSPATH`s on `Winodws` so using the plugin isn't a valid option.

My `module.xml` file is pretty much the default file but I only removed the `enhance` target dependency on `compile` and `copy.metadata`. I'm not compiling my `.java` classes because:

1. I have many libraries to include and it's a headache if I upgrade any set of libraries.
2. I don't need to because eclipse actually does that

And I removed the part that archives the whole project folder because I'm just building a JAR.
        
        -->

```
        <echo message="==================================================================="/>
        <echo message="Enhancing the MODULE files"/>
        <echo message="==================================================================="/>

        <!-- the classpath to enhance -->
        <path id="module.enhancer.classpath">
            <pathelement location="${module.classes.dir}"/>
            <path refid="module.lib.classpath"/>
        </path>

        <!-- define the task enhancer -->
        <taskdef name="nucleusenhancer"
                 classpathref="module.enhancer.classpath"
                 classname="org.datanucleus.enhancer.tools.EnhancerTask" />

        <!-- enhance -->
        <nucleusenhancer classpathref="module.enhancer.classpath"/>

    </target>

    <!--
    ===================================================================
    TARGET : modulearchive
    ===================================================================
    -->
    <target name="modulearchive" depends="enhance">
        <mkdir dir="${module.archive.dist.dir}"/>
        <delete file="${module.archive.dist.dir}/${module.archive.dist.file}"/>
        <zip zipfile="${module.archive.dist.dir}/${module.archive.dist.file}">
            <zipfileset  dir="${module.classes.dir}"  prefix="" includes="**/*"/>
        </zip>
    </target>
```

Also I'm having this warning that wouldn't go away no matter what I do!

```
<taskdef name="nucleusenhancer"
                 classpathref="module.enhancer.classpath"
                 classname="org.datanucleus.enhancer.tools.EnhancerTask" />
>>>E:\Projects\Core - Module\${module.lib.dir} does not exist.
```

My module.properties file isn't changed much. I commented properties for `WAR` building and uncommented properties for `JAR` building:

```
#######################################
# SAMPLE FOR JAR MODULE (commented out)
#######################################
module.dir=./
module.lib.dir=${module.dir}/lib/dn
module.lib2.dir=${module.dir}/lib/deps
module.classes.dir=${module.dir}/target/classes
module.src.java.dir=./src/main/java
module.build.debug=on
module.archive.dist.dir=dist
module.archive.dist.file=${name}.jar
module.archive.files=**/*
```

The folder `lib` beneath my project's folder holds 2 folders, datanucleus main jars for RDBMS while the other folder holds datanucleus dependencies. My compiled classes are beneath `target`.

The output is simply the following:

```
Buildfile: E:\Projects\Core - Module\build.xml

default:
        [echo] ===================================================================
        [echo] Welcome to the build.
        [echo] ===================================================================

enhance:
        [echo] ===================================================================
        [echo] Enhancing the MODULE files
        [echo] ===================================================================
[nucleusenhancer] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (DataNucleus.Enhancer).
[nucleusenhancer] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[nucleusenhancer] DataNucleus Enhancer (version 3.1.0.release) : Enhancement of classes
[nucleusenhancer] DataNucleus Enhancer completed and no classes were enhanced. Consult the log for full details

modulearchive:
         [zip] Building zip: E:\Projects\Core - Module\dist\my-module-name.jar

distribution:
        [echo] ===================================================================
        [echo] Module file ready at: dist/my-module-name.jar
        [echo] ===================================================================
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

The enhancement is an actual modification to the compiled classes. If you are not compiling the classes first, there will be nothing for it to enhance.

Comment: Eclipse is handling the compiling process